# Phonegap & AngularJS - ngCookies does not work on Android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I have a button with the following ng-click function (Controller1):

```
   attachToChat: function(id, what, how){
        //save attach type to cookie and redirect to chat detail view
        $cookieStore.put('attachToChat', {id: id, what: what, how: how });
        $scope.fn.goTo('chat/'+id);
    }
```

... where fn.goTo uses the $location to change current page.

When the page successfully changes, I have the following cookie handler (Controller2):

```
//Handle attach file to chat
//
var attachInfo = $cookieStore.get('attachToChat');
if(attachInfo) {
    //remove attachToChat info from cookie
    $cookieStore.remove('attachToChat');

    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.alert('Attach: '+ attachInfo.what + ' -> ' + attachInfo.how);
    },1000);
}
```

Here I'm wrapping the alert function inside $timeout because I was receiving an "digest in progress" error after routechange & the alert notification was showing up before routechange.

#### The problem

On android device (4.4.4) & simulator (5.0) I'm not receiving any alert notification.

Working on: iOS (7 & 8) simualtor, all browsers & inside Phonegap Developer app.

I have tried to wrap the whole block inside $timeout and did the same in controller1 attachToChat function. Issue persists.

***UPDATE: it seems that this has nothing to do with AngularJS, but with Phonegap, especially Android platform. I've made some tests with pure JS (document.cookie) and it doesn't work either.

#### Workaround

Using html5 localStorage & sessionStorage instead of ngCookies module.
I made some tests using older 1.3.x angularjs versions and the issue persists. It might be something related to angularjs or phonegap..
This are my services for local & session storage, in case somebody wants a quick fix for this issue:

```
MYAPP.factory('storageLocal', ['$window', function($window){
    var storageLocalMethods = {};

    //fn: set
    //desc: set a local storage variable
    storageLocalMethods.set = function(name, value){
        $window.localStorage.setItem(name, angular.toJson(value));
    }

    //fn: get
    //desc: get a local storage variable
    storageLocalMethods.get = function(name){
        return angular.fromJson($window.localStorage.getItem(name));
    }

    //fn: remove
    //desc: remove a variable from local storage
    storageLocalMethods.remove = function(name){
        $window.localStorage.removeItem(name);
    }

    return storageLocalMethods;

}]);

MYAPP.factory('storageSession', ['$window', function($window){
    var storageSessionMethods = {};

    //fn: set
    //desc: set a session storage variable
    storageSessionMethods.set = function(name, value){
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem(name, angular.toJson(value));
    }

    //fn: get
    //desc: get a session storage variable
    storageSessionMethods.get = function(name){
        return angular.fromJson($window.sessionStorage.getItem(name));
    }

    //fn: remove
    //desc: remove a variable from session storage
    storageSessionMethods.remove = function(name){
        $window.sessionStorage.removeItem(name);
    }

    return storageSessionMethods;

}]);
```

Comment: Why dodn't you use just $rootScope ?

Comment: I didn't want to bloat the $rootScope, I like to keep it clean and as someone here said ``The $rootScope shouldn't be used to share variables when we have things like services and factories.``